# /users/integrations/slack/<user id> leads to 404 on other SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams, 404-not-found

While trying to change my profile on MSE, I accidentally tapped "Slack Integrations" on the left, which brought me to a 404 page.

> [image]

Should such thing exist only on SO and MSO? Should it be hidden on all other SE sites?

Comment: I agree that this looks like a valid bug report, but I'm 99% certain that the Teams team monitors MSO more than MSE, so I'm going to migrate this post over there to be on the safe side.